# Open and close contactform on user clicks with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to build a website with a contactform. I want the form to show when a menuitem is clicked and close when the user clicks outside the form. I have managed to get the javascript right for opening the form, but when I click on any of the forms child elements, such as an input, it automatically closes. What is wrong?

Here is the code:

```js
const hideContactForm = document.getElementById('kontakt');
  const showContactForm = document.getElementById('vis_kontakt');
  const form = document.getElementsByClassName('mail_form')[0];
  const formChildren = form.children;

  showContactForm.addEventListener('click', showForm);
  hideContactForm.addEventListener('click', hideForm);

  function showForm () {
    hideContactForm.style.display = "flex";
  }

  function hideForm (event) {
    for (let i = 0; i < formChildren.length; i++) {
      if (event.target != form) {
        hideContactForm.style.display = "none";
      } else if (event.target == form) {
        hideContactForm.style.display = "flex";
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
 <div id="kontakt">
  <div class="midtstill">
    <form class="mail_form" action="kontakt.php" method="post">
      <h2>Bestill opplæring</h2>
      <input id="navn" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Navn..">
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-mail..">
      <input id="tlf" type="tel" name="tlf" value="" placeholder="Tlf..">
      <textarea id="melding" name="message" rows="6" cols="40" placeholder="Melding.."></textarea>
      <button type="submit" name="button">Kontakt meg</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What element in your code has the ID of `vis_kontakt`?

Comment: A click event handler on `kontakt` will trigger when any of its children are clicked. You could probably ensure that the `event.target` is in fact the `kontakt` element, or stop the events from propagating using `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: @j08691 I'd imagine OP excluded the "Show" button for sake of MCVE but did not omit the listener as well.

Comment: It is a list item element (li) that has The ID of vis_kontakt. Thanks for your reply Calvin Nunes!